# Django equivalent of PHP's date

Tags: php, django, function, date

Does anybody know something similar to function date() from PHP in Django?

I'm starting to learn this nice framework, I'm very happy with it (at the momment) but i haven't found that function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

[**`date`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#date)

> Formats a date according to the given format.
>
> Uses a similar format as PHP’s date() function (http://php.net/date) with some differences.

For example, you can do:

```
{{ value|date:"D d M Y" }}
```

If value is a `datetime` object (e.g., the result of `datetime.datetime.now()`), the output will be the string `'Jul 22 2013'`.

Documentation:

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#date
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#date-format
- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#naive-and-aware-datetime-objects